# Ilusão óptica linhas paralelas

Tags: javafx, drawing

Tenho o seguinte exercício que me pede para desenhar uma ilusão óptica como a seguinte:[image: Ilusão óptica parede do café]

Mas não estou a conseguir arranjar uma maneira simples de fazer o codigo de maneira a que ele faça esta progressão em que vai um quadrado para a frente depois alguns para tras. Agora tenho isto falta-me os "desvios":

```
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.embed.swing.*;
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.scene.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;


public class Ilusão2  {  
    private Pane pane;
    private void start(Stage primaryStage) 
  {
    primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(
        e -> Platform.runLater( () -> {Platform.exit(); System.exit(0);} ) 
  ); 

    // https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html
    this.pane = new Pane();
    this.pane.setPrefSize(750, 600);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(this.pane, Color.BLACK));
    primaryStage.show();

    this.squares(10);
    this.lines(1);
} // END start

/**
 * Add shape to pane 
 */
public void addShape(Shape shape)
{
     Platform.runLater(() -> this.pane.getChildren().add(shape));
}

/** execute this method to start the program
 * executing the code in method start(Stage primaryStage) 
 */
public static void start()
{
    Ilusão2 drawingApp = new Ilusão2();
    drawingApp.launch();
}

public void launch()
{
    // Initialises JavaFX:
    new JFXPanel();
    // Makes sure JavaFX doesn't exit when first window is closed:
    Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
    // Runs initialisation on the JavaFX thread:
    Platform.runLater(() -> start(new Stage()));
}

public Ilusão2() 
{
    super();
}

private void squares(int squares)
{
    int width = 50;
    int heigth = width;
    for(int j = 100;j<=450;j+=50)
    {
    for(int i =50;i<=700;i+=100)
    {
     Rectangle square = new Rectangle(i,j,width,heigth);
     square.setStrokeWidth(3);
     square.setStroke(Color.GREY);
     square.setFill(Color.WHITE);
     pane.getChildren().add(square);
    }

    // for (int i = 50;i<=1000;i+=100)
    // {
     // for(int k = 0;k<=600;k+=50)
     // {
         // Rectangle squaresLow = new Rectangle(i,k,width,heigth);
         // squaresLow.setStrokeWidth(1);
         // squaresLow.setStroke(Color.GREY);
         // squaresLow.setFill(Color.WHITE);
         // pane.getChildren().add(squaresLow);
        // }
    // }
}
}

private void lines(int lines)
{
 int xInit= 0;
 int xFin=750;
 for(int y = 100;y<=500;y+=50)
 {
 Line line = new Line (xInit,y,xFin,y);
 line.setStrokeWidth(3);
 line.setStroke(Color.GREY);
 pane.getChildren().add(line);
}

}
} // END class World
```

Este código faz:

[image: Tentativa de ilusão]

Comment: Pela figura, o que você precisa é criar uma sequencia onde a linha abaixo seja um pouco adiantada em relação a primeira, e a terceira seja um pouco atrasada em relação a segunda. E repetir esses 3 exemplos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu adicionei um pouco de código que, basicamente, verifica qual é a linha de retângulos que está sendo criada na iteração atual do loop e define o incremento apropriado na *posição X* (cada linha tem seu próprio incremento na *posição X*, que pode ser 0, 20, ou 40). É esse incremento que está criando os "desvios" que você falou.

Veja o resultado:

> [image: Resultado obtido pelo código abaixo (ilusão de ótica similar ao desejado)]

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Ilusao2 {
    private Pane pane;

    private void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(e -> Platform.runLater(() -> {
            Platform.exit();
            System.exit(0);
        }));

        // https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html
        this.pane = new Pane();
        this.pane.setPrefSize(710, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(this.pane, Color.BLACK));
        primaryStage.show();

        this.squares(10);
        this.lines(1);
    } // END start

    /**
     * Add shape to pane
     */
    public void addShape(Shape shape) {
        Platform.runLater(() -> this.pane.getChildren().add(shape));
    }

    /**
     * execute this method to start the program executing the code in method
     * start(Stage primaryStage)
     */
    public static void start() {
        Ilusao2 drawingApp = new Ilusao2();
        drawingApp.launch();
    }

    public void launch() {
        // Initialises JavaFX:
        new JFXPanel();
        // Makes sure JavaFX doesn't exit when first window is closed:
        Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
        // Runs initialisation on the JavaFX thread:
        Platform.runLater(() -> start(new Stage()));
    }

    public Ilusao2() {
        super();
    }

    private void squares(int squares) {
        int width = 50;
        int heigth = width;
        int linhaAtual = 0;
        for (int j = 100; j <= 450; j += 50) {
            for (int i = 10; i <= 700; i += 100) {
                int xIncremento = definirIncrementoEmX(linhaAtual);
                Rectangle square = new Rectangle(i + xIncremento, j, width, heigth);
                square.setStrokeWidth(3);
                square.setStroke(Color.GREY);
                square.setFill(Color.WHITE);
                pane.getChildren().add(square);
            }
            linhaAtual++;
        }
    }

    private int definirIncrementoEmX(int linhaAtual) {
        int xIncremento;
        if (linhaAtual == 0) {
            xIncremento = 0;
        } else if (linhaAtual == 1) {
            xIncremento = 20;
        } else if (linhaAtual == 2) {
            xIncremento = 40;
        } else if (linhaAtual == 3) {
            xIncremento = 20;
        } else if (linhaAtual == 4) {
            xIncremento = 0;
        } else if (linhaAtual == 5) {
            xIncremento = 20;
        } else if (linhaAtual == 6) {
            xIncremento = 40;
        } else if (linhaAtual == 7) {
            xIncremento = 20;
        } else if (linhaAtual == 8) {
            xIncremento = 0;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Há mais Linhas que o esperado!");
        }
        return xIncremento;
    }

    private void lines(int lines) {
        int xInit = 0;
        int xFin = 750;
        for (int y = 100; y <= 500; y += 50) {
            Line line = new Line(xInit, y, xFin, y);
            line.setStrokeWidth(3);
            line.setStroke(Color.GREY);
            pane.getChildren().add(line);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        start();
    }
} // END class World
```

A implementação do método "`definirIncrementoEmX(...)`" é simples de entender mas é limitada; você pode substituir esses ifs/elses (que **não** são uma implementação flexível, pois só trabalham com número limitado de linhas possíveis) por uma implementação melhor, que seja capaz de retornar o incremento apropriado para qualquer número de linhas (atualmente só funciona até `linhaAtual` ser 8, o que é o suficiente para o exemplo dado).